# Request-scoped beans not working in Spring tests with Cucumber

Tags: java, spring, cucumber

I have an application based on Spring 4.3.28 (i.e. not Spring Boot!) and I want to migrate my  integration tests to Cucumber.

I’ve followed this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/cucumber-spring-integration) and adapted it to plain Spring.

The tests I’ve written so far are working fine (Spring context is initialized etc.), but as soon as there are request-scoped beans involved, they stop working:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you
referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a 
request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating 
within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running 
outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use 
RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

I’ve created a small [sample project](https://github.com/zudljk/request-scoped-cucumber)
that tries to reproduce the problem.

There is one context configuration class called AppConfig:

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
   @Bean
   @Scope("request“) // when this line is removed, the test succeeds
   public ExampleService exampleService() {
      return new ExampleService();
   }

   @Bean("dependency")
   @Scope("request") // when this line is removed, the test succeeds
   public String dependencyBean() {
      return "dependency bean";
   }
}
```

The ExampleService is request-scoped, and gets one request-scoped bean injected by @Autowired:

```java
public class ExampleService {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("dependency")
  String dependencyBean;

  public String process() { return "I have a "+dependencyBean; }
}
```

For the tests, I have one Spring-annotated superclass:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestBase {

  @Autowired
  public ExampleService underTest;
}
```

There’s also a plain Spring test that runs just fine:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ExampleServicePlainSpringTest extends TestBase {

  @Test
  public void whenProcessingDataThenResultShouldBeReturned() {
    assertThat(this.underTest.process()).isEqualTo("I have a dependency bean");
  }

}
```

The Cucumber test is executed by this test class stub:

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class ExampleServiceCucumberTest extends TestBase {}
```

The actual cucumber step definitions are here:

```java
public class CucumberStepDefinitions extends TestBase {

  private String result;

  @When("I process data")
  public void iProcessData() {
    result = this.underTest.process();
  }

  @Then("the result should be returned")
  public void checkResult() {
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo("I have a dependency bean");
  }
}
```

The .feature file for Cucumber is in the src/test/resources directory under the same package name as the step definitions class:

```
Feature: Example

  Scenario: Example service bean returns dependency
    When I process data
    Then the result should be returned
```

Usually when I encountered the „no thread-bound request found“ error, it was because the `@WebAppConfiguration` annotation was missing, or when I tried to inject a request-scoped bean into a non-request scoped bean. But that’s not the case here.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At a glance everything is correct. Cucumber uses Springs TestContextManager but doesn't trigger its before/after method hooks because Cucumber doesn't have a single method. You may have to create a request context in your test or submit a fix to Cucumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to resolve it; the updated code is in the github repository linked in the question.

When using the `SpringRunner`, the request context is initialized in a `ServletTestExecutionListener` that is implicitly added to the list of `TestExecutionListener`s for the test.
The initialization happens in the `beforeTestMethod()` method of that listener.

However, as @M.P.Korsanje correctly remarked in the comments (thanks!), Cucumber doesn't have test methods, so `beforeTestMethod()` is never executed.

My solution was to add a custom subclass of `ServletTestExecutionListener` as a `TestExecutionListener` that delegates the `beforeTestClass()` call to the `beforeTestMethod()`:

```java
public class ClassLevelServletTestExecutionListener extends ServletTestExecutionListener {

  @Override
  public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    super.beforeTestMethod(testContext);
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    super.afterTestMethod(testContext);
  }
}
```

And in `ExampleServiceCucumberTest`:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class})
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners(ClassLevelServletTestExecutionListener.class)
// extend the Spring class to get the default TestExecutionListeners
public class TestBase extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

  @Autowired
  public ExampleService underTest;
}
```

Comment: Nice hack! Would you mind creating an issue out of this on github? I think this should be supported properly without the need to hack.